# Unable to find xPath SELENIUM JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have issue keep throw error of unable to find the xpath , as i set the loop for opening this xpath to insert data . Although i set the time wait for existance to 60secound but it still couldn't find it. I been trying alot method calling this by using title or status hence it still not working . Kindly advise

HTML :

```
<a href="javascript: void edit('edit_total_amt')" title="Override total tax amount" onmouseover="status='Override total tax amount'; return true">91.14</a>
```

CODE :

```
public void clickOnItemTax () {

        By xPath = By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'edit_total_amt')]");

        this.sleep(3);
        if (this.waitForExistence(xPath,60))    {
            WebElement domLink = linkGet(xPath); 
            domLink.click();

        } else  {
            JLog.fail("Unable to find a writable item taxdialog!");
        }

    }
```

-waitforExistence

```
public boolean waitForExistence(By by, int timeoutSeconds){
        boolean exists = false;
        Long polling_interval = (long) 250;
        Long timeout = (long) timeoutSeconds * 1000; // in seconds
        Long elapsed = (long) 0;
        while (elapsed <= (timeout)) {
            if (exists(by)) {
                exists = true;
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(polling_interval);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                JLog.warning(JLog.getStackTraceAsString(e));
                break;
            }
            elapsed += polling_interval;
        }
        if (elapsed >= timeout) {
            JLog.warning("waitForExistence waited for " + timeout/1000 + " seconds, but unable to find: " + by.toString());
        }   
        return exists;
    }
```

Thanks you

Comment: Is it throwing any errors? if any post the stacktrace/error log.Is it possible to give the link of the site?There is no problem with xpath

Comment: it throw error : [2015-07-23 01:06:34 PDT] WARNING: waitForExistence waited for 60 seconds, but unable to find: By.xpath: //a[contains(@href,'edit_total_amt')]
[2015-07-23 01:06:34 PDT] FAIL: Unable to find a writable item taxdialog!

Comment: sorry i can't give the link due company policy

Comment: using XPath is an unreliable way of finding the elements. You should try as much as using CSS , Ids and classes to find the element. Can you please try using this "a[title='Override total tax amount']" as CSS path

Comment: Can we see your `waitForExistence()` method? This code you're showing looks fine as it is.

Comment: Try this xpath:  //a[@href='javascript: void edit('edit_total_amt')'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an internal company webpage could I suggest that you give the  an 'id' to make your life easier. If not you can do this. I'm always surprised by people writing their own wait method when you could use either the implicit or explicit wait time in Selenium.

The former is as follows, the only thing to be aware using this method is that when looking for an element it will always wait this long. It is however a much safer way to write your scripts looking for elements and doesn't bloat your code:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

if (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("//*[@title=\"Override total tax amount\"]")).size()!=0)
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//*[@title=\"Override total tax amount\"]")).click();
}
else
{
     JLog.fail("Unable to find a writable item taxdialog!");
}
```

The explicit way to do it would be as follows where 10 is your seconds:

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
 .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("//*[@title=\"Override total tax amount\"]")));
```

See the following link for more on this.
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp